# Why are two of my menu "Font Awesome" icons suddenly showing as squares?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, menu, font-awesome

Please see:

https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk

[image]

I have seen other questions. I donj't understand why all of a sudden a few of my font awesome icons now show as squares when they did not before.

- Donations
- Facebook

The code is correct:

```
<li id="menu-item-1010" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1010">
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.facebook.com/publictalksoftware"> 
        <i class="_mi _before fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>Facebook</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

It is still visible in the menu editor:

[image]

They were always fine. I understood that the icon set used by [Menu Icons by ThemeIsle](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-icons/) are **Font Awesome 4.7**.

On my iPad these two icons simply don't show any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change class of "**fa**" to "**fab**". See below to example

Before

```
<i class="_mi _before fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

After Use class "**fab**" instead of "**fa**"

```
<i class="_mi _before fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not according to the 4.7 specs: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/facebook-square

Comment: As mentioned, it was working fine (for years) until this morning.

Comment: It is 5.x specs that use `fab` https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-square?style=brands

Comment: also have more than 1 version of font awesome defined - they are overriding each other

Comment: @ObmerkKronen How do I identify that issue in the source? Are you saying I have 4.7 and 5.0 on my site?

Comment: Yes version issue of `fontawesome`

Comment: You are using awesome 4 and 5 for the same time that's why you facing this kind of problem

Comment: How do I identify that fact in the source?

Comment: I am installing the "font awesome" plugin and investigating

Comment: You need to check you header file or for just checking you can check by inspecting element

Comment: Remove plugin and use **CDN** for awesome

Comment: I am confused. :( I see it show the right one (must be 4.7) and then flash over with the 5. I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: Ok.... 1. after installing font-awesome plugin it identified a list of plugins causing conflicts. One of them was my "easy facebook Like".  disabling that stops the problem I was having. But it also raises the fact that my main website theme is 4.7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203898/discussion-between-aman-and-andrew-truckle).

Answer (score 1):

I've checked their site its **fab** not **fa**!
https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-square?style=brands

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
this
<i class="_mi _before fab fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Yes, for version 5. Not version 4.7. Please see my comment added to the existing answer.

Comment: Oh yes! thought you haven't mentioned it. Thanks bro